# How I can change background color of query editor in Workbench?

Tags: lubuntu, gui, accessibility, mysql-workbench

I have dark GUI, but how I can make text editor also dark?

I am under Lubuntu, Workbench from repositories.

[image]

Comment: Please test the solution (my system is updating and stalled ... so I need to fix that 1st before I can test the env setting) :)

Answer (score 2):

This used to drive me crazy too... until now, I just found an solution that a reddit user posted here: [Disable GTK theme for specific application? | reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Fedora/comments/adx8nj/disable_gtk_theme_for_specific_application/edl0440)

Basically you edit the command to run the workbench app by right clicking on its desktop icon. Then prepend the command field with the following text:

`env GTK_THEME=Adwaita`

so in full it reads: `env GTK_THEME=Adwaita mysql-workbench %f`

Click Save, then start the application.

*Note that this config you specify will be saved by default in your home folder: .local/share/applications/mysql-workbench.desktop file*

So now you can enjoy your desktop dark theme and not suffer using workbench too!

Comment: where to type : env GTK_THEME=Adwaita mysql-workbench %f ??

Comment: Add it to the .desktop entry (./local/share/applications/mysql-workbench.desktop)

[Desktop Entry]
...
Exec=GTK_THEME=Adwaita;mysql-workbench %f
...

Answer (score 1):

From bug #1:

> Several areas of the workbench seem to be hard coded to having a white background. This basically makes a really good looking tool like MySQL Workbench virtually inaccessible and unusable for me.

(from the bug report)

- http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?153,368243,368346
- http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?152,398334,398512#msg-398512
- Bug #1: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=52485
- Bug #2: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=64013

But now why Linux owns Windows... bug 2 has this comment:

> Fixed as of the upcoming Workbench 5.2.43, and here's the changelog entry:
>
> On Linux, the "WB_FORCE_SYSTEM_COLORS" environment variable was 
>    added. Enabling this variable (with a value of 1) will disable 
>    MySQL Workbench from using its own color scheme. 
>    Example usage: `export WB_FORCE_SYSTEM_COLORS=1`. 
>    This is useful for certain conditions, like when using the 
>    HighContrastInverse or GnomishDark system themes.

Comment: Where I need to write this?

Comment: You can do this command line for testing. You can add it to `.bashrc` if it works and you want it permanent.

Comment: here are some methods in adding env vars: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables (the .desktop file might be the one you also need to do this from the launcher)

Comment: I typed in Lubuntu terminal `export WB_FORCE_SYSTEM_COLORS=1` - zero effect.